# What’s the characters on this seal of the vase? (Characters identified: 景德鎮製)

Tags: character-identification

Found this vase at home.
There is a seal with some characters on it.
Is anybody able to read the words? 
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is 景德鎮製.

Read it vertically.

```
鎮景
製德
```

Answer (score 1):

The seal should be: **景德鎮製**, where **景德鎮** is famous for the ceramics artifacts in China 江西 province.